# Searching for month by name in database with month/day/year format

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to develop a search system with php and Mysql, but how do you search for : example the month of march when the date format in the database is 2012-03-26(year/month/day)

Comment: Convert `march` to `3` and search

Comment: You want all the March dates no matter what year, or only one particular month of dates?

Comment: When you say "when the date format in the database is [...] (year/month/day)", does that mean the dates are stored in a VARCHAR column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the mysql [MONTH()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month%22month%28%29%22) function like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MONTH(date_column) = 3
```

to search for March for example, or there is also MONTHNAME() function like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MONTHNAME(date_column) = 'march'
```

Comment: This sort of "convenience" programming is a performance disaster waiting to happen. For a dataset of any size this is a bad approach as comparing a constant to the result of a function on a column renders indices useless. Look at orourkek's answer and the further comment by Catcall

Comment: It seems a bit complex, and its a search where the user enters the month name, so how would i do it?

Comment: How does the user enter the month name? If you use a select then you can have the integer value as the values - `<option value="1">January</option>`. Otherwise just use an array of month names indexed by month number `array(1 => 'January', 2 => 'February', etc)`.

Comment: They select the month name from a dropdown list

Comment: You will probably have to write a small amount of code to process your form and build a suitable query but this is a much better option than just writing the simplest, yet inefficient, query. Whatever you do, avoid the solution suggested in this answer. It is a very bad habit to get into.

Comment: @nnichols did you actually perform a test to confirm this? MONTH() is a native mysql function that operates on date columns. If you use orourkek's approach, the native date column must first be converted into a string in order to be compared, thus adding overhead and processing time to the query. Technically to optimize orourkek's approach, you should be casting the strings to dates

Comment: @BrianGlaz - no I did not perform a test! This is really basic database stuff that seems to be misunderstood by many. Feel free to test it. The string values given in orourkek's query will be implicitly cast to DATETIME (should actually be date as pointed out by Catcall). Using the MONTH() or MONTHNAME() function will require the date column to be evaluated in every row.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the format of the column data, something like this could work: (one of many solutions)

```
SELECT [whatever] 
FROM [wherever] 
WHERE `date` < '2012-03-31 23:59:59' 
AND `date` > '2012-03-01 00:00:00'
```

Comment: for example if im searching for march, how would it relate?

Comment: Upvoted as better than using month() and monthname(), but you'd be better off using `date < '2012-04-01'` instead of `< '2012-03-31 23:59:59'`.

Comment: @Catcall - Good point. It all depends on how the data is structured, and how it will be used once retrieved.

Comment: @dames - You'd have to do some data processing for the request before you send it to the database, wherein you convert the month to a number (or directly to a DATETIME/TIMESTAMP format)

Comment: This kind of expression would use an index. The month() and monthname() functions would have to be called for every row, though, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like

```
SELECT   keyword ,  description , url FROM searchTable WHERE MONTH(addDate) = '3' 
SELECT   keyword ,  description , url FROM searchTable WHERE MONTHNAME(addDate) = 'March'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather crude example of how you might handle the date in your search form -

```
<form method="get" action="">
    Year:
    <select name="year">
        <option value="2012">2012</option>
        <option value="2011">2011</option>
        <option value="2010">2010</option>
    </select>
    Month:
    <select name="month">
        <option value="1">January</option>
        <option value="2">February</option>
        <option value="3">March</option>
    </select
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="search"/>
</form>
<?php

if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
    $year = intval($_GET['year']);
    $month = intval($_GET['month']);

    $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM `table`
            WHERE `date` BETWEEN '$year-$month-01' AND LAST_DAY('$year-$month-01')";
}
```